# IntelliJ, Akka and Configuration files

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, akka, sbt-idea

When using [akka](http://akka.io/), I place `akka.conf` in `src/main/resources`. When I `run` through sbt, the `akka.conf` is correctly recognized. But not when I run through IntelliJ (even after a `gen-idea`). What is the appropriate way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Put the `.conf` extension in `Settings` (`Preferences` on Mac) | `Compiler` | `Resource Patterns`.

Comment: I also found that I had to trigger a rebuild for the project before the configuration is picked up in the unit tests.